# Program received SIGKILL error in the main.m

Tags: iphone, sigkill

I am receiving an error in my main thread when i am trying to load a table with data being supplied from a different thread than main thread.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
[pool release];
return retVal;
```

please could anyone help me solving this....
}

Comment: Well in that case you need to paste some code where you are fetching the data .

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable NSZombies?

If not here is how you do it?

- Goto: Product-> Edit scheme
- Choose Ran tab
- Select "Arguments"
- In the Environment Variables add
- NSZombieEnabled and set its value to YES

Run your code. It should tell you where you have an error.